# Unable to bring Microsoft Office installation to an end on macOS Catalina after computer went off

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, install, ms-office, error

I was in the process of installing Microsoft Office when my computer went off.

When I tried installing Microsoft Office back, it showed me this error:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed (com.apple.installer.page controller error -1.)
```

Comment: Which version of Microsoft Office were you trying to install? Were using the standalone version (that is, the version that can be downloaded from Microsoft) or were you trying to install the Mac App Store version?